# What is the difference between Content Memory Addressing (CMA) and Content Addressable Memory (CAM)?

Tags: memory, addressing

I have been looking over the internet for Content Memory Addressing(CMA) but whenever I search for it I get  Content Addressable Memory (CAM). So I am confused, is CMA and CAM the same thing. If possible please provide some explanation or resource for both.

Comment: I have never heard of Content Memory Addressing, but I have only been doing this for forty years. Where have you come across the term, and in what context? (Add links to the question if possible)

Comment: My understanding of Content Addressable Memory is that it's one of those things which the Comp-Sci Ph.D's like to pretend actually exists when they play with their high-level algorithms, but in the real world gets implemented using "normal" memory along with some kind of search or sort mechanism.

Comment: @brhans there are ( * ) physical implementations of CAM, and small ones are pretty easy to roll your own in FPGA, but you are correct for a practical definition of "real world". ( * Or were ... I don't know what Micron did with MUSIC Semiconductors ) https://www.eetimes.com/micron-acquiring-assets-of-music-semiconductor/

Comment: CMA might be the same thing but translated from another language.